# wix 3.0. В каком атрибуте Feature размещаются варианты установки?

Tags: wix

В каком атрибуте Feature размещаются варианты установки как на скриншоте?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации сказано, что это можно реализовать через атрибуты Feature.
В моей ситуации реализовано через три файла:

- В .wixlib  `<String Id="UITextMenuNetwork" Overridable="yes"><![CDATA[Будет установлен для выполнения через сеть]]></String>`
- В .wxs  `<UIText Id="MenuNetwork">!(loc.UITextMenuNetwork)</UIText>`
- В .wxl  `<String Id="UITextMenuNetwork" Overridable="yes">Будет установлен для выполнения через сеть</String>`

Если через Orca зайти, то можно поправить значение атрибута Feature.